# Facebook Application display blank page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-canvas, facebook-fbml

i have created one Facebook application (using CanvasFBMLBasePage) in Asp.net more than 2 years ago, and it was working fine.

i tried to check it today, and it was just shows me blank page.

in debug tool, it gives Response Code: 200

Errors That Must Be Fixed
Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

in Scraped URL: it shows me below response

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><redirect url="http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=...&amp;v=1.0&amp;next=Default.aspx"></redirect></head></html>
```

i have also added SSL url which was not there when created application.

not sure why suddenly application stops working, as i have not changed anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's been so many changes to platform in the last two years it could be anything.
If it was an FBML app, it's completely broken and needs to be reimplemented as an Iframe app.
If it was using Oauth 1 it probably displays OK but login is broken, etc.

From your question it appears to be FBML related, in which case you need to reimplement the app using the current APIs instead of the old FBML tags

Comment: Thanks igy, when i hit the url in browser http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=...&amp;v=1.0&amp;next=Default.aspx (url i got in response as in question), it actually shows page of my application (though not 100% proper), so is there something that i can change settings and it works, rather than create new application.

Comment: You should probably start with the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) docs as you just linked to the old auth flow which isn't supported anymore